# Format Specifier

Tags: java

```
package iCanDoIt;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("i" + "\t" + "square root");
        int i;
        double squareRoot;


        for(i=50; i>=1; i--){
            squareRoot=(Math.pow(i, 0.5));

            System.out.println(i+ "\t" + squareRoot);
    }

    }
    }
```

how can I have two digits after the decimal point?

for example: 
if i=49 
I would like square roote of i=7.00 ------------ INSTEAD OF i=7.0

I am thinking you should use format specifier, %f.

I tried doing `System.out.print( i + "\t" + "4.2f",squareRoot);` but didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

use `System.out.format` instead of `System.out.print`:

```
 System.out.format(i+"\t%.2f", squareRoot);
```

`%.2f` means that the second argument should be printed as a float with two decimal places

here's the full documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

If you want this to work like println does, you should add `\n` at the end of first parameter:

```
System.out.format(i+"\t%.2f\n", squareRoot);
```

Comment: I tried System.out.format one you mentioned above. Unforunately, output was completely different from System.out.println output... =(

Comment: what was the difference
?